# Java, Tomcat не видит WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Tags: java, mysql, servlet, tomcat, jdbc

Пытаюсь разобраться с сервелетами в java, и приложениями в WAR архивах. И у меня проблемы с простым примером. Вот такая структура файлов в Томкатовском webapps/

```
.
└── myapp
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    └── WEB-INF
        ├── classes
        │   └── src
        │       └── MyMainServlet.class
        ├── lib
        │   ├── mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
        │   └── servlet-api.jar
        └── web.xml
```

Вот такой код в MyMainServlet.java

```
package src;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyMainServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        //someMethod();
        System.out.println( "Hello World!!!" );
    }


    public void someMethod()
    {
        String s_sql = "";
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stm = null;

        try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somebd", "root", "root123456" );
            stm = con.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate( s_sql );
        }
        catch( SQLException sqle ) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }
        finally
        {
            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /* ... */ }
            try { stm.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /* ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас все работает, при переходе по нужному урлу, в логах печатается Hello World!, но стоит раскомментировать someMethod(), как выкидывает эксепшн:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somebd
```

Очевидно что томкат не видит либу mysql. Если ее кинуть в общее либохранилище томката, все работает. Но мне хотелось бы сделать полностью автономный варник.

Вот так выглядит манифест:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_72 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: src.MyMainServlet
Class-Path: ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar ./servlet-api.jar
```

**Решено добавлением Class.forName()**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somebd", "root", "root123456" );
```

Comment: Решение не принято добавлять в ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте строчку:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

Перед созданием соединения(connection). И всегда когда используете JDBC не забывайте загружать драйвера таким образом т.к. `DriverManager.getConnection()` ищет драйверы среди загруженных классов, а не пытается загрузить их сам. Так же стоит заметить, что наличие классов в classpath(в вашем случае в WEB-INF/lib) не приводит к их автоматической загрузке класс лоадером.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал про это. И когда я писал простые консольные/оконные приложения с упаковкой в jar, мне почему-то это не требовалось, и все работало без `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. Еще раз, большое спасибо. Теперь работает, коннект с БД есть.